# Can i call the salesforce Add products screen from a VF page?

Tags: visualforce

I have VF page and i am trying to add Opportunity products  from the VF page itself. I love the way the add products screen is currently in lightning experience.

My question is Can we someway utilize the add products screen as its currently in lightning experience from a call from VF page ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

For Classic/VF you could utilize http://www.michaelforce.org/2011/04/03/snazzy-product-entry-screen/ as a starting point.

Comment: I thought about this before and abandoned the idea of customizing because of how powerful the component is currently. The issue is that is a lot of javascript and you can't just call the action like you can other actions. I have created a custom one in Lightning, but that was because it was not on parity to classic when i did it. The amount of work it takes just to get it slightly better is probably juice that ain't worth the squeeze.

Comment: Re-building standard components is a pain and should be carefully considered, I agree. As an ISV, we're sometimes out of luck, though :)